# What is the difference between LinearRegression class and Support Vector Machine(SVM) class with parameter kernel='Linear'?

Tags: svm, linear-regression

I used the class LinearRegression() and now i am studying Support Vector Machines which has parameter kernel="Linear"? What is the difference between them?

Comment: the difference is at least in that SVN classifies into 2 classes only (by means of separating the points by hyperplane) while linear regression might classify into 2 or more classes

Comment: but i have read somewhere svm can be used with more than two classes by using decision_function_shape='ovr'

Comment: can you please clarify?

Comment: you're right about multiclass svm, that was out of scope of my knowledge. have you checked this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46970888/difference-between-linearregression-and-svm-svrkernel-linear

Comment: thanks for the link.But i am still not able to get the difference